# How to increase Chart size dynamically inside a table in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0

I have a range bar chart inside a table of row group and the chart is repeatedly generated according to a category.  I want to increase chart height dynamically based on a category.

suppose

```
if category =A THEN CHART HEIGHT=10CM

if category =B THEN CHART HEIGHT=7CM
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the Properties of the chart there is a field called DynamicHeight, which will, as suggested, dynamically change the height of the chart based on a value.

For example I have set a parameter called Offset to default to 8.

You can then set the value of DynamicHeight to 
=CStr(Parameters!Offset.Value) + "cm"

Then, as you change the Offset parameter, the width of the chart changes.

> `DynamicHeight = 8`
>
> [image]

and

> `DynamicHeight = 4`
>
> [image]

Now how you calculate the height to be a meaningful and consistent is up to you... I get the impression you wouldn't want to use a parameter like the example above, but I'm sure it would be possible to create a calculation that will give you a sensible layout.

**Update**

Note it is not possible to alter the DynamicHeight on a table that is recreated multiple times in a Matrix.

I believe this is because the size of the chart area is determined to generate the layout of the report, and this area is then populated with the actual chart later in the rendering process.  It doesn't know until the later stage that is should be a smaller size, so therefore is not the smaller size.

Comment: yes,you are right ,it will work but my requirement is chart is inside a table row group and it will create multiple chart according to category to category and there it will not increase height category to category

Comment: See update added to the answer above, stating that what you are after isn't actually possible with SSRS